# The request could not be submitted for background processing?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I am getting the following error using Crystal Reports 10.5 on my development machine.  The report was working fine this morning in my testing and now I get this error

> Error in File C:\DOCUME~1\UserNameHere\LOCALS~1\Temp\BarLabel {052E0DE7-59FA-4C55-B293-316F7DFE8531}.rpt:
>   The request could not be submitted for background processing

I am not sure what caused the problem or how to fix it.  I have deleted the temp files and that didn't do anything.   I also gave the "Network Service" account on the computer list priveleges as I saw that fixed an error similar to this in CR 9.0 and that didn't seem to help either.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the error was an internal error of CrystalReports.   I was using a BarCode font that didn't exist on the server.  The error is non descriptive but was due to something wrong with the report and not the CR runtime